# What is the difference between "to pee" and "to take a pee"?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between *to pee* and *to take a pee*? Is *I am peeing* correct or should we say *I am taking a pee*? Please elaborate on the correct usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'correct' usage, as both are colloquial expressions. I suppose *take a pee* has the added sense 'go away for a few minutes for that purpose'.

Incidentally, *pee* is a euphemism for *piss* - it's just the letter P spelled out.

Comment: I would suppose that 'taking a pee' was always deliberate, while just 'pee' might not be. An American friend made me pause for a moment when she said that she was disgusted, during a walk in a park, to see that someone had 'been to the bathroom' behind a tree. As a result, my wife and I now often say 'Do bears go to the bathroom in the woods?' to say that the answer to a question is obviously "yes".

Answer (score 1):

They have the same meaning, just like "swing" and "take a swing". Both "pee" and "swing" can be either verb or noun.

By the way, in my experience (I live in the U.S.), "take a pee" is much less common than "take a piss" (though "piss" is usually considered a bit more vulgar).

Comment: Pee is a euphemism for piss, so it makes sense that piss is more vulgar.

Answer (score 0):

**Take** in *take a pee*, is an example of a [**delexical verb**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/delexical-verbs-have-take-make-give-go-and-do).  A delexical verb is a way of taking the meaning of a verb out of the phrase and giving it to a noun instead, and using a relatively meaningless verb like *take* or *have* instead:

- I pee / I take a pee
- I drink / I take a drink
- We argue / We have an argument
- She looks at it / She has a look at it

It doesn't make much difference to the meaning, but sometimes one phrasing is more common than another, or is considered more polite than another.

Also, using a delexical verb lets you use an adjective or a participle to describe something about the action when there isn't any good way to use an adverb.  Consider **I took a *much-needed* pee**.  It's difficult to say that simply with an adverb!